# JQuery not attaching dynamically generated checkbox to modal with first click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

When a click event fires, a modal will be presented to end-user and pre-populated  with checkboxes.
The issue I am encountering is that at the first click of the button, the pre-populated checkboxes do not render on the modal.
If I exit out of the modal and click the button again, the modal then properly displays the checkboxes.

Why is this happening?

```js
(".changeCheckBoxList").click(buttonClickHandler);

function buttonClickHandler() {
  var button = $(this);
  swal({
    html: true,
    title: ""
    text: $('#chkbox')
    
  },
    function(isConfirm)){
      if (isConfirm)
      {
        $.post({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/SomeController/AddCheckboxesData',
          datatype: 'json',
          data: {
            //
          }
        
        }).done (function(results) {
          
        });
      }
    };
    
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'html',
      url: '/SomeController/SomeActionResult'  //This is getting back the correcting data
    }).done(function (results) {
    
      //dynamically generating the checkboxes below
      $.each(results, function(key, value) {
        var div = $('<div><input type="checkbox" value="someValue" + <label for= key></label></div>');
        div.find('label').text(results[key].Name);
        $('#chkbox').append(div);
        
      });
    
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default changeCheckBoxList" type="button" data-id="">n</button>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="chkbox">
        <div>
            <label for="examplecheckbox"> Click a checkbox</label>
            <input type="text" id="">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```